# Understanding powering op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, single-supply-op-amp

I am working with an op-amp LM741. I'm not using it for audio applications, just simple DC voltage stuff for educational purposes. As long as the output is ultimately a positive voltage (think non-inverting amplifier), is it always ok to power it with +Vcc and GND instead of +Vcc and -Vcc? Or, will the feedback be messed up if the op-amp can't produce negative voltages? Take the series voltage regulator for example ([Source](https://www.theengineeringknowledge.com/introduction-to-linear-series-regulators/)):

[image]

My understanding is supplying the transistor with a negative voltage wouldn't make much sense so I would love to know if I can save the hassle and just connect the op-amp to +Vcc and GND.

Comment: 'just simple DC stuff' - then use a modern rail2rail amplifier if you want to keep it 'just simple'. Or use a 'single rail' type like the LM324 if you need to go to ground, but your VCC can be supplied with some extra margin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As long as the output is ultimately a positive voltage (think non-inverting amplifier), is it always ok to power it with +Vcc and GND instead of +Vcc and -Vcc?

The only reason to have a negative supply rail is if you might at some point have an output, *or input* that is "low enough". If the op-amp is rail to rail, "low enough" means "negative". That is, if one of the inputs (or the output) is negative, you will need to have a negative supply rail. However, many op-amps, including the rather old 741 cannot operate properly at voltages too close to the supply rails. Thus, if you use a 741, you will need a negative supply rail if you want an input or the output to go down to say 2V (that's positive 2V!) and work correctly. In a worst case, it may not operate correctly below 3V unless there the low supply rail is negative.

> Take the series voltage regulator for example ... I would love to know if I can save the hassle and just connect the op-amp to +Vcc and GND.

If you use a rail-to-rail op-amp, yes, you can use GND for the low rail. You can also use GND for the low rail if the output voltage is sufficiently high, as explained above. But that means don't try to use a 741 in a 1.8V regulator. Many would say, don't use a 741 ever, because there much better alternatives on the market.